# Export data rest api

Tags: rest-api, bulk-api

I want to expose my service to another system using rest api. Once the system calls the service they should be able to download the all the accounts data(1mn) in csv format.

Can I achieve this using rest api?

Or

Do I have to use bulk api 2.0 methods and query the data and return in csv format?

I need some suggestions over this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve that. You can implement your RESTFUL Salesforce service.

Read and follow [documentation about Apex Rest](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST)